# Allow leading zeros on a worksheet with EP Plus

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

Hi I am using Ep Plus with a web application. I am creating an Excel file that the user can fill out and upload back to the application. When I enter in a number with leading zeros, they are truncated.

Is there away to allow leading Zeroes to be entered by the user?

Comment: The User will be editing the Excel file with MS Excel after downloading the file. I need to format the column to allow leading zeros

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format that I needed was "@" so the line of code was

```
codeSheet.Cells["A:D"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "@";
```

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer for this question did not work for me. I found this article from Microsoft which solved my problem. https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/81518/using-a-custom-number-format-to-display-leading-zeros

I was dealing with zip codes so I was able to do this:

```
workSheet.Column(4).Style.Numberformat.Format = "00000";
```

This works since my zipcodes will always be 5 digits.

Answer (score 3):

Playing around with the style of the `ExcelRange` you can achieve what you want:

```
var range = // get the range you want
// Force the numbers to have 2 digits to the left and 1 digit to the right
// of the decimal place.
range.Style.NumberFormat.Format = "00.0"
```

You can play with the different formats available by opening Excel and playing with the number format dialog.

[image: Format Cells]

Comment: Thanks that was what I needed to get me going in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the insert or cell formatting as `text` not number than it should allow you to  use leading zero

```
string text  = "'0001"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 Excel.Range formatRange;
    formatRange.NumberFormat = "@";
```

Comment: Please elaborate your answer

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.