# EP Plus @ Format Not Working

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I am having trouble getting EP Plus to format as text so I can keep the leading zeros of a number.

[This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098569/allow-leading-zeros-on-a-worksheet-with-ep-plus) has a code snippet I tried but could not get to work. Here is the snippet:

```
workSheet.Cells[row, col].Style.Numberformat.Format = "@";
```

The only way I could get it work is with the code below, but I do not want a set number of place holders.

```
workSheet.Cells[row, col].Style.Numberformat.Format = "0000000";
```

Here is my full code, I've tried it in reverse order with the same result.

```
workSheet.Cells[row, col].Style.Numberformat.Format = "@";
workSheet.Cells[row, col].LoadFromText("000001");
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`LoadFromText`](https://github.com/pruiz/EPPlus/blob/master/EPPlus/ExcelRangeBase.cs#L1771) is mostly used to import CSV into range(not a single cell).

---

The only way to actually keep stored a number with leading `0`s while keep it at an arbitrary length is to store it as `TEXT`.
For `TEXT` value, simply set the `Value` and don't touch the `NumberFormat` :

```
sheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "000001";
```